# Does subscribeOn for combineLatest do something?

Tags: rx-java

Is there any sense in adding `subscribeOn()` after `Observable.combineLatest()` like so:

```
Observable.combineLatest(
  someObservable,
  theOtherObservable,
  (something, theOther) -> iAmFunction(something, theOther)))
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
  ...
```

What I understand `iAmFunction()` will be called on whatever Scheduler the being-combined-Observable emmit as last.

So what's the purpose of that `subscribeOn()` at the end?

Answer (score 4):

`subscribeOn` specifies where the subscription side-effects will happen and does not guarantee you get items on the thread it uses. Use `observeOn` instead:

```java
Observable.combineLatest(
    someObservable.observeOn(Schedulers.single()),
    theOtherObservable.observeOn(Schedulers.single()),
    (something, theOther) -> iAmFunction(something, theOther))
)
```

What `combineLatest` does upon subscription is to subscribe to its sources, thus transitively you subscribe to `someObservable` and `theOtherObservable` on the `computation()` Scheduler's thread. Note, however, that if `someObservable` does not give control back, `theOtherObservable` will not get subscribed to. It is always better to specify `subscribeOn` as close to the source(s) as possible:

```java
Observable.combineLatest(
    someObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()),
    theOtherObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()),
    (something, theOther) -> iAmFunction(something, theOther))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this question, the `subscribeOn` decides `which thread executes the iAmFunction()` ([Link](http://reactivex.io/documentation/scheduler.html)). Basically `subscribeOn` decides emitting thread.

> the SubscribeOn operator designates which thread the Observable will begin operating on, no matter at what point in the chain of operators that operator is called.

For example there are two combineLatest logics.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    Observables.combineLatest(
        Observable.just("o1"),
        Observable.just("o2")
    ) { _, _ -> Thread.currentThread().name }
        .subscribe {
            println("Without subscribeOn")
            println("in combineLatest: $it")
            println("in subscribe: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        }

    println()

    Observables.combineLatest(
        Observable.just("o1"),
        Observable.just("o2")
    ) { _, _ -> Thread.currentThread().name }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe {
            println("With subscribeOn")
            println("in combineLatest: $it")
            println("in subscribe: ${Thread.currentThread().name}")

        }

    Thread.sleep(500)
}
```

```
Without subscribeOn
in combineLatest: main
in subscribe: main

With subscribeOn
in combineLatest: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
in subscribe: RxComputationThreadPool-1
```

As you can see `subscribeOn` changes the thread for `combineLatest` and `subscribe`. If you don't use `observeOn`, it can effect from `emitting items` to `subscribe`.

Comment: how can you explain CachedThreadScheduler / ComputationThreadPool?

Comment: This is incorrect. `subscribeOn` specifies where the subscription side-effects will happen and does not guarantee you get items on the thread it uses.